# convert php code to C (sha1 algorithm)

Tags: php, c++, cryptography, converters, sha1

`PHP` code:

```
<?php
$pass = "12345678";
$salt = "1234";
echo sha1($salt.$pass.$salt);
?>
```

My `C` code to use `SHA1` using the openSSL crypto library at:http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html.

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main()
{  
  const char str[] = "Original String";
  const char salt[] = "1234";
  const char pass[] = "12345678";
  strcat(str, salt, pass);
  unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // == 20

  SHA1(str, sizeof(str) - 1, hash);

  // do some stuff with the hash

  return 0;
}
```

My question is, how can i modify the `C` code to the exact same thing as the `PHP` code?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `strcat()` to concatenate the salt?

Comment: @Barmar i don't know C that well if you could show me how to do that i'd appreciate it.

Comment: No. Please make an attempt to figure it out yourself, then we'll help you fix it if it doesn't work. That's how you learn.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Barmar I added code changes, can i get some help now? I tried my best with assigning appropriate variables and trying to use strcat. How do i make the result of strcat into a variable which i can then use inside the SHA1 function?

Comment: @ntoskrnl i updated the code, help please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate enough space in the string for the concatenated string. Also, you can't modify a `const char`, so don't use that modifier on the variable that you're concatenating into.

```
char str[17] = ""; // 16 characters plus null terminator
const char salt[] = "1234";
const char pass[] = "12345678";
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH+1]; // +1 for null terminator

strcpy(str, salt);
strcat(str, pass); // strcat() only takes 2 arguments, you need to call it twice
strcat(str, salt);

SHA1(str, strlen(str), hash);
```

You should also consider using `std::string` instead of char arrays in C++.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```c
SHA_CTX ctx;
SHA1_Init(&ctx);

const char salt[] = "1234";
const char pass[] = "12345678";

SHA1_Update(&ctx, salt, strlen(salt));
SHA1_Update(&ctx, pass, strlen(pass));
SHA1_Update(&ctx, salt, strlen(salt));
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1_Final(hash, &ctx);
```

There is no need for an intermediate concatenated string. The constant for the hash size is already there. And the size of the strings can just be retrieved using `strlen`.

Furthermore, in cryptography it is useful to represent bytes as unsigned chars in C - and this is also the type of the hash in `SHA1_Final` argument list.